# Procedure or function GetJobs has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, repeater

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

I have this SQL code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [site].[GetJobs] 
    @Locale char(2) = NULL
   ,@jid INT = NULL
   ,@limit INT = 10000
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP (@limit)
        JO.PrimaryKeyID
        ,coalesce(GT.translation, JO.Title) As Title
        ,coalesce(GT3.translation, JO.LongDescription) As LongDescription
        ,coalesce(GT5.translation, JO.Experience) As Experience
        ,JO.Image
        ,JO.ClosingDate
        ,JO.OrderIndex
        ,JO.Active
    FROM 
        [Jobs] JO
    LEFT JOIN 
        ln_GenericTranslations GT ON GT.DbTable = 'Jobs' 
        AND GT.dbfield = 'Title' and GT.DBRecordID = JO.PrimaryKeyID AND GT.locale like @Locale
    LEFT JOIN 
        ln_GenericTranslations GT3 ON GT3.DbTable = 'Jobs' 
        AND GT3.dbfield = 'LongDescription' and GT3.DBRecordID = JO.PrimaryKeyID AND GT3.locale like @Locale
    LEFT JOIN 
        ln_GenericTranslations GT5 ON GT5.DbTable = 'Jobs' 
        AND GT5.dbfield = 'Experience' and GT5.DBRecordID = JO.PrimaryKeyID AND GT5.locale like @Locale
    WHERE 
        JO.Active = 1
        AND (JO.PrimaryKeyID = @jid OR @jid IS NULL)
        AND ((DATEDIFF(dd,GetDate(), JO.ClosingDate) >= 0) OR JO.ClosingDate IS NULL)
    ORDER BY 
        JO.ClosingDate DESC, JO.PrimaryKeyID DESC
END
GO
```

I have it linked up to a repeater however when I run the page it gives me this error:

[image: Error in Visual Studio]

Does anyone know why this is occurring? I've looked up similar answer but none that seem to help me! All I know is the exact same stored procedure has been used before and it worked fine?

If you need any added info let me know!

Added Repeater code:

```
<Engine:WidgetSQLDataSource ID="DS_Jobs" runat="server" SelectCommand="site.GetJobs" />
 <asp:Repeater ID="rp_jobs_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS_Jobs">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div class="jobs jobs_list span6">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="item">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Visible='<%#!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("Image"))%>'
                        NavigateUrl='<%#  CommonFunctions.GetTreeURL(Convert.ToInt32(Resources.Pages.Jobs), "jid=" + Eval("PrimaryKeyID"))%>'><img src="/uploads/images<%#Eval("Image")%>" alt="<%# Eval("Title") %>" /></asp:HyperLink>

                    <h2><%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
                    <p><%# CommonFunctions.StripHTML(Eval("LongDescription").ToString(), 200) %></p>
                    <a href="<%#CommonFunctions.GetTreeURL(Convert.ToInt32(Resources.Pages.Jobs), "jid=" + Eval("PrimaryKeyID"))%>" class="button button_view"><%= Resources.Text.More %></a>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </div></div></div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

     <% if (rp_jobs_list.Items.Count == 0 && Request.QueryString["jid"] == null) { Response.Write("There are currently no items in this section."); } %>
```

Backend:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DS_Jobs.SelectParameters.Add("Locale", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString());
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["jid"] == null)
        {
            rp_jobs_detail.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            DS_Jobs.SelectParameters.Add("jid", Request.QueryString["jid"]);
            rp_jobs_list.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the repeater code? I assume you set more than 3 parameters.

Comment: Added code calling the sproc and repeater. I'll have a look at clearing parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you add the `limit` parameter?  That is not defined here.  Also, on page postbacks, these parameters may not be persisted on the server, and thus you would need to recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the previous parameters were not cleared from `DS_Jobs.SelectParameters` and are being carried over somehow, resulting in "jid" being added multiple times.

You could try modifying your code to clear the parameters first, then re-add them all:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["jid"] == null)
    {
        rp_jobs_detail.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        DS_Jobs.SelectParameters.Clear();
        DS_Jobs.SelectParameters.Add("Locale", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString());
        DS_Jobs.SelectParameters.Add("jid", Request.QueryString["jid"]);
        DS_Jobs.SelectParameters.Add("limit", /* what's the limit? */ );

        rp_jobs_list.Visible = false;
    }
}
```